# HTML Layout Design

Tags: html, layout

I'm not skilled in HTML, but I'm in need of simple layout as below in ASP.Net MVC Razor. [image]

> I need HTML/CSS with 4 sections as below
>
> 1. Div1 having Grid @ left side full
> 2. Div2 having buttons @ right side top
> 3. Div3 having Grid @ right side center
> 4. Div4 having Grid @ right side bottom

I've tried below sample code , problem is Left side (Div1) overlapping with Right side section not aligning correctly.

```
    <div class="left">
    <div id="div1">
        <p>Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3</p> 

    </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div id="div2">
        <p>DIV 2 DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2DIV 2 DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3</p>

    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <p>DIV 3 DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3DIV 3/p>

    </div>
</div>


<style>
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? Ideal candidate for css grid or flexbox.

Comment: I'm using Edge browser

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) is perfect for what you need, see below I have adapted [this example](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example12/) to your case.

You should definitely go through all the examples of [this website](https://gridbyexample.com/) done by Rachel Andrew.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
}

.header div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" "sidebar content" "sidebar footer";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">
    <div>
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <button>Button 3</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Button 4</button>
      <button>Button 5</button>
      <button>Button 6</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Button 7</button>
      <button>Button 8</button>
      <button>Button 9</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box content">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>More content than we had before so this column is now quite tall.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**Resources:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
- https://gridbyexample.com/

Comment: Thanks for your esteemed support....In the attached image, in DIV 2 I've 3 sets of buttons arranged vertically...if would be fine if you send me the code for that

Comment: This can be easily done with Flex. You should have a look at the links in my answers to go further with your project.

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox implementation:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">Left</div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="right">Right Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks James for your kind support. I can place the grid in DIV1, but it occupies half of the webpage, what property do i need to use to shrink the width of DIV1

Comment: The `flex: 1 1 0`. The 1s let you define what fraction each takes up. So you can give the left one `2 2 0` and the right one `1 1 0` and the left one will take up 2/3rds of the screen.